# Trigger GitHub Actions Workflow with environment is created or repo/environment variables are modified

Tags: github-actions

I am working on some IaC patterns and I would like to be able to trigger a workflow when variables are modified.  If something like this was implemented, it would be great to be able to do this with variables(or secrets) at any scope (organization, repository, or environment, but also to be able to control the scope.

When working through IaC, the desired patterns are not easily reconciled and folks implement a lot of bad practices, even according to their own designs.  For instance, folks often cite using Terragrunt to help keep their Terraform code DRY... but it copies the code to environment specific directories, which is the opposite of DRY.

What would be great is to be able to write the code per all of the best practices that suggest to accept variable inputs for everything that might need to change.  Then, variable stores are not common triggers to initiate a pipeline execution, so we need to manually trigger or come up with some other means to accomplish it.

Before I submit an issue request, perhaps someone can correct me if my searching has failed.  Are there are systems out there that can do this without adding more infrastructure?  I know tools like Consult-Terraform-Sync could probably pull this off, but then we have to run Consul... and CTS.